# OSX Swift open URL in default browser

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nsurl, openurl

How to open a URL in the system default browser by using Swift as programming language and OSX as platform?

I found a lot with `UIApplication` like:

```swift
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: object.url))
```

but this works just on iOS and not on OSX

And the [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html), I found has no examples for swift and there is a lot deprecated for OSX 10.10.

Comment: I guess it's because we're supposed to use the new Extensions instead...

Answer (score 161, accepted):

**Swift 3 or later**

```
import Cocoa

let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
if NSWorkspace.shared.open(url) {
    print("default browser was successfully opened")

}
```

Comment: Technically this needs an "if let url = ...", since URL(string:) returns a URL?. Otherwise, great, thank you very much!

Comment: @ApolloGrace well if you know the string will never mutate and it is a valid url you can safely force unwrap the initializer result `URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!` therefore in this case `url` is not optional. `url` type is `URL`

Answer (score 59):

For MacOS, you can use this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com")!
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(url))
```

For iOS, you can use the following:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

You have to unwrap NSURL.

Comment: Why does this have 23 upvotes? Off topic to the question and should be removed.

Comment: This is misleading, as it does not work for the platform used in the question.

Comment: Blame Google that indexed this page this way and all searches for iOS lead hare ... and it's useful :)

Comment: If the URL is nil because the string couldn't be a valid URL, this code crashes.  You need to be careful in Swift when you're using exclamation  points, or the whole program crashes.

Comment: @Kaydell If you're using a string literal or any compile-time constant to create the url, then force-unwrapping it is perfectly fine. In these cases, there's no point in adding any error-handling code; if the value is nil, then that just indicates you made a typo.

Answer (score 15):

macOS:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!)
```

iOS:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://google.com")!)
```

Comment: Good reference for earlier versions of Swift (I'm on 2.3)

Comment: Please describe that the second code block is for iOS

Answer (score 11):

When using **Swift 3**, you can open a webpage in the default browser using the following:

```
NSWorkspace.shared().open(NSURL(string: "https://google.com")! as URL)
```

In the accepted answer above, you can also check a URL using **Swift 3** by inputting the following:

```
if let checkURL = NSURL(string: "https://google.com") {
    if NSWorkspace.shared().open(checkURL as URL) {
        print("URL Successfully Opened")
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid URL")
}
```

I hope that this information helps whomever it applies to.

Comment: As this is Swift 3, I don't think NSURL is necessary any more - just use URL: 

NSWorkspace.shared().open(URL(string: "https://google.com")!)

and

if let checkURL = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
    if NSWorkspace.shared().open(checkURL) {
        print("URL Successfully Opened")
    }
} else {
    print("Invalid URL")
}

Answer (score 8):

Just a bonus. If you want to **open a URL in a specific browser**(even other client who can handle that URL), here is the **Swift 3** code tested on Xcode 8.2.1 and macOS 10.12.2.

```
/// appId: `nil` use the default HTTP client, or set what you want, e.g. Safari `com.apple.Safari`
func open(url: URL, appId: String? = nil) -> Bool {
  return NSWorkspace.shared().open(
    [url],
    withAppBundleIdentifier: appId,
    options: NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.default,
    additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil,
    launchIdentifiers: nil
  )
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For **Swift 5**, **Xcode 10** and **MAC OS**:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(NSURL(string: "http://www.lichess.org")! as URL)
```

Comment: Just use URL, not both URL and NSURL.  For example:
`if let url = URL(string: "https://www.lichess.org") {
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
}`

Comment: Why would you use `NSURL` and then cast it to `URL` in Swift 5? Why not directly create a `URL`?

Answer (score 6):

**xCode 9 update**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: This is for iOS and not macOS

Answer (score 4):

MacOS Xcode 10  Swift 4.2 update

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
```