# Is there a difference between == true and != false in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, if-statement, boolean, nsurl

I had this code in my Swift App

```
func parseJSON() {

    let urlString = "www.websitethatlinkstoJSONfile.com"

    if NSURL(string: urlString) == true {
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url!, options: []) as NSData
        let json = NSData(data: data!)
```

// more code

However, even though the link actually worked and was true, the if statement was never met and it kept skipping it and moving to else. So I changed the code to

```
if NSURL(string: urlString) != false
```

and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure why though?

Comment: `NSURL(string:)` will return true for any string be it a valid url or just radom characters.

Comment: Using guard statements are encouraged in Swift during situations like this to check for nil.  Also you may want to research the Equatable protocol for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to check for a boolean value when creating a `NSURL`, but rather make sure the `NSURL` you create is non-nil. Try wrapping it it in an if let statement like so to make sure whatever URL's you create are non-nil before executing further code.

```
   let urlString = "www.websitethatlinkstoJSONfile.com"

    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
       if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {
           let json = NSData(data: data)
       } else { 
          //Handle case where data is nil
       }
    } else { 
        //Handle case where url is nil 
    }
```

Using if let statements in this way makes sure that the `NSURL` and `NSData` objects you are creating are non-nil and valid objects and then you can add an `else` statement to them to handle cases where your `url` or `data` objects are nil. This will save you from unwanted crashes due to force unwrapping with the `!` operator.

Comment: When I use ```if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) as? NSData {``` it says Conditional cast from 'NSData' to 'NSData' always succeeds.

Comment: I removed the `as? NSData` from my answer. It was unnecessary casting I had copied from your code.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!!! Now my if and my else is working. Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 3):

As already explained in the other answers, comparing the optional
`NSURL?` against `true` or `false` is not what you want, and you should
use optional binding instead.

**But why does it compile at all? And how can the result be interpreted?**

In `NSURL(string: urlString) == true`, the left-hand side has the type
`NSURL?`, and `NSURL` is a subclass of `NSObject`.
There is a `==` operator taking two optional operands:

```
public func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

The compiler uses the *implicit conversion* of `Bool` to `NSNumber`
to make that compile.  So your code is equivalent to

```
if NSURL(string: urlString) == NSNumber(bool: true)
```

and that will always be false, and

```
if NSURL(string: urlString) != NSNumber(bool: false)
```

will always be true, simply because the left-hand side is not a
number.

Here is a demonstration of the effect:

```
func foo(x: NSObject?) {
    print(x == true, x == false)
}

foo(NSNumber(bool: true))  // true, false
foo(NSNumber(bool: false)) // false, true
foo(NSObject())            // false, false  !!!
```

The last case is what you observed: Both `x == true` and `x == false`
return `false`.

For classes not inheriting from `NSObject` it would not compile:

```
class A { }
let a: A? = A()
if a == true { } // cannot convert value of type 'A?' to expected argument type 'Bool'
```

**Remark:** This is another argument for *not* comparing boolean values
against `true` or `false`, i.e.

```
 if a == true && b == false { ... }
```

is better written as

```
 if a && !b { ... }
```

Applied to your case, you would get a compiler error indicating 
the problem:

```
let urlString = "http://www.websitethatlinkstoJSONfile.com"
if NSURL(string: urlString) {  }
// error: optional type '_' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! I am new to swift, and I appreciate you breaking this down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a different take a look at some of the documentation. In this init method it is fallible.

> public convenience init?(string URLString: String)

the question mark indicates it is fallible.

So  it will return a NSURL object or nil.

```
convenience init?(parameter: AnyObject) {
    if parameter == nil {
        return nil
    }
    self.init()
}
```

So in a specific example like your example. You can test it in playground

```
let urlString = "100"

if NSURL(string: urlString) == true {
    print("true")
    //Never prints in any circumstance//
}


if NSURL(string: urlString) != false {
    print("true")
    //always prints//
}

if NSURL(string: urlString) != nil {
    print("true")
   //object was created//
}
```

Comment: `NSURL.init(string:)` returns `NSURL` object or `nil`. It does not return `false`.

Comment: Thats why said "in a way" to help them understand

Comment: "in a way" would not be suitable here. Because comparing `NSURL?` to `false` can never be considered to be "equal".

Comment: You should note that `NSURL(string: urlString) != false` is always true, even when `NSURL(string: urlString)` returns `nil`. In fact, it's equivalent to `NSURL(string: urlString) != NSNumber(bool: false)`. Test with giving `urlString` an invalid url.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I'm new to Swift so it can be pretty confusing.

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale you may also be interested in looking at https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

Comment: I'm using Cocoa for OS X app development. I have been trying to use the API, but it can be pretty confusing hehe :)

Comment: @cheesydoritosandkale http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704852/osx-swift-open-url-in-default-browser

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator checks whether both side value is equal or not.For example:

```
var data:Int = 6
if data == 5 {
   //if this block is executed that means `data` is exactly equal to 5
   //do something
}
else {
    //In this situation, this block of code will be executed.
   //if this block is executed that means data is anything other than 5.
   //do something
}
```

The `!=` operator checks that two values are not equal to each other.For example:

```
var data:Int = 6
if data != 5 {
    //In this situation, this block of code will be executed.
   //If this block is executed that means `data` is anything other than 5.
   //do something
}
else {
   //if this block is executed that means data is exactly equal to 5.
   //do something
}
```

In your case code `if NSURL(string: urlString) == true` checks that if `NSURL(string: urlString)` return `true` then it should excute `if` block otherwise `else` block.

`NSURL(string: urlString)` is convenience initializer which creates `NSURL` object and returns. In case if it fails to do so then it **returns** `nil`

In any case, it does not return either `true` or `false`.So when you compare this with `true` it always fails and goes to `else` block.

And when you check that it is not equal to false (!= false) becomes true because `NSURL(string: urlString)` returning `NSURL` object and that is not equal to false.

So if you want to check that whether `NSURL` object is created or not you can check whether the return value is `nil` or not.

```
if NSURL(string: urlString) != nil {
   //Object is created successfully.Now you can do whatever you want this object.
}
else {
   //It failed to create an object.
}
```