# Give a new url to the browser with Swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos

I could find a way to open a specific browser (with macOS and Swift):

```
@IBAction func frx(_ sender: NSButton) {
      NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/Firefox.app"))
}
```

Is it possible to give to that Firefox window a new url in a posterior moment and reload the page? (Give the address not when I launch the application but later)

Comment: @Willeke. Thank you. That question is different and does not solve my problem. I am very new to macOS and Swift. As far as I understand, that code seems old as it gives a lot of errors. On the other side, I need to give an address later, not when I launch the application. So, my first problem is to save that window to go back it later.

Comment: Someone posted an answer to a different question which should solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41431381/6782707

Comment: @Edric. Thank you, but as the other case, that is to open a browser with an url, but what I amb looking for is to change the url of a browser that is already opened.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Firefox {
    static func open(path: String) {
        let ff_url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Applications/Firefox.app", isDirectory: true) as URL

        if let www_url = URL(string: path) {
            NSWorkspace.shared.open([www_url], withApplicationAt: ff_url, configuration: NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()) { app, error in
                if let error = error {
                    // handle error
                }
                if let _ = app {
                    // handle success
                }
            }
        } else {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```