# How to deeplink a file from macOS app to browser print preview (like sublime text does)?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

The functionality I'm after is where Sublime Text opens the browser to the print preview of the file currently edited.
This is the following:

1. Have a txt file (in sublime).
2. Select File > Print
   [image: Sublime Text Print]
3. Observe that the default browser opens up to the print preview page (tested in firefox and safari)
   [image: Safari]

The urls seem to point to the file being in a temp directory and generated as a html file.
`file:///private/var/folders/05/q2p__63n3zx9k3yzcb8f9n0c0000gn/T/tmpbfkdzvmq.html`
Note html generation isn't necessary for my use case, remaining as txt is fine.

The answer can be for either swift or objective-c. I'm after **how to open the browser to print preview**.

Comment: What is the question? How to open a file in the default browser? How to tell the default browser to print? Did you try anything?

Comment: "The urls seem to point to the file being in a temp directory" Which URLs?

Comment: The question is how to open a browser to the print preview page for a file that was generated inside a macOS app, ie a text file. The URL displayed in the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSX Swift open URL in default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704852/osx-swift-open-url-in-default-browser)

Comment: Safari opens the Print dialog when it receives a Print Apple Event.

Comment: Regarding that link @Willeke, what I'm after is the url scheme to get the OS to trigger the browser to show the print dialog. I can trigger a link and have the browser open no problem, but what does the url need to contain to inform the browser to open the print dialog? Regarding the Print Apple Event, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer involves using Apple Events as mentioned by @Willeke.
These is the information I found that assisted me:

- https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/apple-events-programming-guide.pdf
- http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:B5zOBQgWUoMJ:mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2082.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ae
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7743420

In pseudo AppleScript code, it would be something like this:

```
tell default browser
    launch
    print document
endtell
```